# Examine the continuity and differentiability of $f(x)=\frac{\sin (\pi[x-\pi ])}{4+[x]^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, derivatives

> Prove that the function $$f(x)=\frac{\sin (\pi[x-\pi ])}{4+[x]^2}$$ where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function, is continuous as well as differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb R$

I tried to solve it like this:
$$\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=f(c)$$
i.e.$$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2} ^+}f(x) =\lim_{h\to 0}f(\frac{\pi}{2}+h)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin 0}{4+\pi^2}=0$$and similarly, $$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2} ^-}f(x) =\lim_{h\to 0}f(\frac{\pi}{2}-h)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin -\pi}{4+(\pi-1)^2}=0$$

Therefore the function is continuous. Please check whether it is correct.
and help me check differentiability using

$$\lim_{x\to c^+}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\to c^-}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$\

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Your function $$f(x)=\frac{\sin (\pi[x-\pi ])}{4+[x]^2}$$ is equal to $0$ for all $x$ since sine of integer multiple of $\pi$ is $0$.